# Can I create SSO with AD without having an ADFS?

Tags: single-sign-on

I received a requirement from my client to create SSO from salesforce to their AD. They do not have an ADFS server and did not provide a certificate nor the issuer (the IDP URL).
the client says he managed to run SSO with sugar-crm without these requirements. can this be true?
I really don't know how to move forward with this client...
Please help..!

Answer (score 2):

Sugar can treats Active Directory like an LDAP directory and query it directly using LDAP.

Salesforce does not have this capability and relies on the use of SAML for which ADFS is needed.

ADFS is not a significant issue problem to install from what I've observed.  There are third party alternatives including Ping Federate, Okta.

As of Winter '14 Salesforce has offered their own Active Directory bridge

All of the solutions I've mentioned involve installing software on the client site to talk to Active Directory and forward the identity they verify to Salesforce using SAML.

Answer (score 1):

Recently released SFDC Identity product allows you to connect AD to SFDC. Take a look at http://www.salesforce.com/platform/identity and the demo at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fnLU0IoNwSw